# why vue-range-component is not working fine in sweet-modal Vuejs

Tags: rangeslider, ion-range-slider, vue-slider-component

I am trying to get Vue-range-component functionality in my project, but it was not loading perfectly on the sweet-modal.
[please check image how range showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbWg1.png)

```
 <vue-range-slider
      v-model="value1"
      :min="min1"
      :max="max1"
    >
    </vue-range-slider>

import VueRangeSlider from 'vue-range-component'
```